# How to deal with signals emitted before slots connected

Tags: c++, qt, race-condition, signals-slots

I have a somewhat more complicated version of the following code:

```
void Foo::makeConnection(...) {
    QTcpSocket * socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    // ...
    socket->disconnect(this);
    emit connectionAppeared(socket);
}

void Bar::baz() {
    // ...
    connect(foo, SIGNAL(connectionAppeared(QTcpSocket*)), this, SLOT(onConnectionAppeared(QTcpSocket*)));
    foo->makeConnection(...);
}

void Bar::onConnectionAppeared(QTcpSocket * socket) {
    if (!socket) { std::terminate(); }
    socket->setParent(this);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(socketClosed()));
}
```

The `Bar::baz` asks `Foo` to make it a connected `QTcpSocket`, and after it is made, the socket's signals are connected to `Bar`'s slots. But there is a problem with timing: the `readyRead` signal may very well be emitted befor it is connected to any slots, and thus is effectively lost. We "fixed" it like this:

```
void Bar::onConnectionAppeared(QTcpSocket * socket) {
    // ... same code as before plus the following line:

    emit socket->readyRead(); // Kick it to get started!
}

void Bar::readData() {
    while (mSocket->bytesAvailable()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem of losing `disconnected()` signals is still there, but it doesn't manifests very often. Technically, I could emit `disconnected()` manually, and check `socket->state()` in the `socketClosed()` slot... but I just feel it's not the right way. I effectively just manually examine the current state instead of reacting to state transitions which I was the whole point of signal/slot machinery.

Are there nice ways to fix this kludge? I thought of passing signal/slot pairs to `Foo::makeConnection(...)` somehow, so they can be connected before `socket->connectToHost()` is called, but I don't know how, and I am not sure it's the good idea anyway.

Comment: So why don't you emit `connectionAppeared` right after you initialize the `socket` object?

Comment: @thuga Because connection has not appeared yet and may never appear? `connectionFailed()` signal exists too. And in fact, inside `makeConnection` I may have to create two TCP-connections (the first is the auxiliary one) and "return" the second one created.